# System was slow when Elasticsearch is enable

Tags: elasticsearch, magento2.4.3

I have installed Magento 2.4.3, in Ubuntu 18.04.6 LTS,

my system configuration is
RAM 8 GB,
HDD 500 GB,
but whenever I enable Elasticsearch, and run Magento on the browser,
the system was slow and sometimes it stuck very much,

so what should I do for my system to go smoothly?
if I use SSD instead of HDD so the systems can work speedly or not?

please give me some suggestions on this.

Thank You.

Answer (score 2):

I used to face this kind of issue but now after using SSD it is not only smooth but also fast and more fun

If you do not want to change SSD then go for docker (a little hard to configure)
But for using docker - 16GB of ram is recommended.

Happy coding

Answer (score 2):

Improve your system configuration, Set 16GB Ram and if possible try to setup SSD. I have a system with 480 SSD, 16 GB RAM and Core i5 8th Generation.

Elasticsearch required high bandwidth and utilise RAM. If you don't want to improve your system, pleas enable Elasticsearch while run commands. and then disable Elasticsearch Service. You can work as per requirement only setup:upgrade command run you need to enable Elasticsearch service.

Answer (score 1):

Elastic search will consume around 4 GB of memory.

So instead of 8 GB go for 16 GB Ram.

SSD is a must have.

Check how much memory is consumed by elastic search as this will also depend on data size, attribute configuration, number of stores on your site.

Answer (score 1):

One more thing i would like to suggest that in elastic search there will be one configuration file where you can set minumum and maximum memory size.

```
/etc/elasticsearch/jvm.options
```

-Xms1g
-Xmx1g

Just set this above value to 512MB.